# Adding a gap between two table columns

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a HTML table with a gap between **just one** pair of columns. The only solution I could think of was to create two tables and put them side by side with some margin in-between, however this seems unnecessarily complex for what I'm trying to achieve.

More specifically, I'm trying to create a calendar display in CSS, with a decorative gap between the weekends and weekdays, see image below:
[image: Calendar Example]

EDIT: Here's some indicative markup

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th class="add-left-gap">Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="add-left-gap">2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- and so on... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And some CSS:

```
.add-left-gap {
    /* this doesn't work because table cells don't respect margins, 
       but it shows what I'm trying to accomplish */
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please add your markup and stylesheet as well.

Comment: Table cells can’t have margins. I think the only way to achieve this might be by formatting the elements _inside_ those cells to fake the effect.

Comment: Instead of table layout, you could make a list layout. In that case, you would have more control over spacing. Example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_calendar.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert empty `<th>` and `<td>` tags and remove their border.

```css
table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.gap {
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
     <th>Monday</th>
     <th>Tuesday</th>
     <th class="gap"></th>
     <th>Wednesday</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="gap"></td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one line in your table css:

```
table{
    border-spacing: 10px 0px;
}
```

Using border-spacing property you just make top and bottom border space 0 and apply left right space.